# What's a good way to handle data across Prod, Dev, Test DB's in Rails 3 (using Cucumber)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

I have a small Rails 3 app (you have a listing with photos, and prices), and am trying to get into Cucumber BDD testing.

I have 2 types of Database data:

1) 
There's consistent data (like a table of price ranges) that needs to be the same across my Prod, Dev, and Test servers.

2)
Then there's the other data that can change from each environment (like usernames, listing data etc). I just need to make sure I have a good spread of data in my dev and test servers that matches data that should / would be in prod.

I have 2 questions.

First:
What's the best way to handle data like this? How can I ensure consistency across the different environments in a painless way?

Second:
I'm using fixtures to populate my **dev db**. I'm having a hard time populating my **test DB**. What's the best way to populate the test DB (while using Cucumber) so I can run through my scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4932f7b38f72104819022abca0c952ba6f9888cb

The idea behind db/seeds.rb is for that kind of data that is pretty much static and needs to be universal. Anything in that file will be pulled in during db:setup, and can be added manually with rake db:seed

second question should be straight forward, rake db:fixtures:load should not be dependant on enviornment. So you should be able to do something like `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:fixtures:load` and that should load up your test database with your fixture data.

Answer (score 3):

as suggested, db/seeds can be used for some use cases, you can also checkout this solution: http://jedschneider.posterous.com/using-semi-static-data-as-an-activerecord-mod that may address other use cases.

In regards to cucumber, the true cucumber philosophy would be to create a resource through the web interface, eg to create a user: go to user sign in, register, sign in as that user. They [discourage direct model access](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/cucumber.pdf) (page 292 ish), but it is too convenient to not do, in my opinion, as long as the web interface workflow is also tested.

For this, I prefer using factories over fixtures as they are less fragile in on-going development. I would recommend [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or `factory_girl_rails` for Rails 3. Thus you can have a step definition:

```
/Given a valid user exists?/ do
  @user = Factory(:user)
end
```

which populates the user table with a user an creates an instance variable that you can use to follow through the scenario with. If you want to use fixtures with cucumber, setup a [before hook](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) that will load your fixtures for you.